# Attempt at retrieving SSID

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, netsh

Im trying to build a windows based web applet that grabs the SSID that the PC is connected to! This is what im currently doing but I would love to see another method or an improvement of this. The idea is to let JavaScript send request to the applet and then append the values of a text box with the response from the Java applet.

JavaScript

```
 var ssid = applet.getNetworkParameter("SSID", networkInterface);
```

Java

```
public String getNetworkParameter(final String parameter, final String arg1){
setAppletStringReturnValue("");
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction(){
  public Object run() {
    try {
if (osName.indexOf("win") > -1)
{
  this.osNetDriver = new Windows7NetServices();
}

if (parameter.equals("SSID")){
        SmartConfig.this.setAppletStringReturnValue(SmartConfig.this.osNetDriver.getSSID(arg1));
 }
  }
    }
    return null;
  }
 });
return this.appletStringValue;
}


public String getSSID(String interfaceName){
try
{
String cmd = "NETSH WLAN SHOW INTERFACE";
boolean parsingAllowed = false;
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
pr.waitFor();

BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
{
  String[] arr = line.split(":");
  if (arr.length >= 2)
  {
    String parameter = arr[0].trim();
    String value = arr[1].trim();

    if (parameter.equals("Name"))
    {
      parsingAllowed = value.equals(interfaceName);
    }

    if ((parameter.equals("SSID")) && (parsingAllowed))
    {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
}
return "";
}
```

Comment: How would you like this to be improved. Fewer lines of code, faster, nicer code structure... Unless you tell us what you don't like about this code (is it working for you?) it's hard to know what you want "improved"...

Comment: Simplicity would be a great improvement!